# How to change 0% to display as 0 in Store Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, mysql-workbench, mysql

In my sp, I have a column name as percentage. In that column it will display percentage of amount but i want to change if the percentage column displays 0% it will display as only 0.

Comment: Why have you got both `mysql` and `sql-server` as tags?  Which are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest one:

```
CASE
    WHEN [Your_Column] = '%0' THEN 0
    ELSE [Your_Column]
END AS alias
```

Answer (score 0):

USE REPLACE FUNCTION IN SQLSERVER AND MYSQL:
Edited: To replace only the records which has 0% value in table.

```
SELECT REPLACE(COLNAME,'0%',0) FROM TABLENAME where len(colname)=2
```

Comment: This is not correct. this one replace something like 20% to 20

Comment: @sqluser: What if, if i add where add condition to the above code.<where len(colname)=2>

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE statement.
For MySQL check [THIS](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-statement/) for reference

and for MS SQL check [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for reference

The code could be something like:

```
SELECT  CASE percentage WHEN '0%' THEN '0' ELSE percentage END
FROM <your_Table>
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

for `sql-server 2012`

```
select IIF([your column]='0%',0,[your column])
```